# New Install using Old Database

Tags: attributes, orders, products, customer-account, migration

My company has a slow magento site that we want to start over on, without re-entering a lot of the information, eg:

- All types of products (over 3000 in 4 stores)
- All attributes
- Customer Records
- Orders, Invoices, Shipments, etc
- Promotions
- Newsletter Subscribers, etc..

Is there a way I can do a new install of Magento (currently running 1.8.1), install our new theme files, then pull in all of the above mentioned information?

We have extensions on the current site that will not be used on the new site. I am worried about remnants of theme files/settings and those extensions being in the database tables.

Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Normally the reason magento is slow is 90% Database related. To many products, url rewrites, bloaded log tables, bad server/configuration and so on.

But there is a change that theme, extensions, or just bad coding can help to this. 
To really give you an answer info is needed on your server configurations and such.

The only way to get all this data is upgrading your magento then intalling a new one with this same database. We've done this a lot

Backup DB.
Upgrade Magento (so all tables needed are added and modified)
Then delete Magento install new one with same database.

But with just upgrading and setting a new theme will be almost as good i suspect.

Getting a real clean install is better, products, attributes and such can all be imported. but orders, invoices and such not. there are extensions but we personally have never found any good extension without giving us a head-ace.

Hope this insights help you.